# Не удалось пробразовать varchar в numeric

Tags: c#

Я не понимаю почему, с самого начала во всех строках на всякий случай прописал Convert.ToDecimal, ошибка все равно есть. Прикладываю все строки где используется переменная. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
CostBooks.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Цена"]) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text)); //textBox2.Text - Количество товара

foreach (decimal c in CostBooks)
                    { TotalCost = TotalCost+c; }

command = new SqlCommand("INSERT into [Receipt] values ('"+Convert.ToInt32(ReceiptNumber)+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(StaffNumber)+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(CustomerNumber)+"','"+Convert.ToDecimal(TotalCost)+"')", myConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //На этой строке вылезает ошибка
```

Comment: Пробовал так `decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Цена"]) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
                            CostBooks.Add(a);` , ошибка осталась

Comment: так ты посмотри какой ты sql собираешь - ты values делаешь как строки, а не числа - потому что сам их в кавычки оборачиваешь

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Grundy дело говорит: в SQL вставка в таблицу чисел должна выглядеть как `INSERT INTO [Receipt] VALUES (22, 33, ...)` - без оборачивания в одинарные кавычки.